# Ending a sentence with に

Tags: particle-に

Looking the に particle up on jisho.org, it says that it could also function as a because of~ or even for the purpose of~ but I'm still uncertain if that's the case in the following sentence:

> 二人で歩み寄って許し合える関係に

I think it means "Meet halfway for your relationship to be one where you can forgive each other." but I still don't know how に functions in this sentence.

Is the sentence incomplete by any chance? Or is it already grammatical by itself?

Comment: It simply means "In a relationship where you can compromise and forgive each other". に means 'in' here. The sentence is incomplete. What maybe implied to come after can only be determined from context.